# Flutter determinate Linear Progress Bar not animating after the value changes

Tags: flutter, animation

I want my linear progress bar to update progressively in stages, each time a user answers a question correctly in a quiz I have made.

I can't seem to get the progress bar to animate upon the value changes, however.

To note:

-My animation runs successfully, if I call my _animationController.forward from initState() (with some test values in the tween).

-I notify my AnimationController to run via notifications triggered using the Provider package as shown in the code below, when a question has been correctly answered, which is working.

-there are two values (original and new) that are input into the animation tween to tell the progress bar how much it should animate each time, are also correctly updating as this log shows.

```
I/flutter (18664): original value 0.0 and new value 0.0
I/flutter (18664): original value 0.0 and new value 0.25
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:learn_to_read/controllers/answerManager.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class AnswerProgressBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnswerProgressBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AnswerProgressBarState createState() => _AnswerProgressBarState();
}

class _AnswerProgressBarState extends State<AnswerProgressBar>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late Animation<double> _anim;
  late double _originalValue = 0;
  late double _newValue = 0;
  late int _localPoints;
  late double _valueCompleted;

  @override
  void initState() {
    double _originalValue = 0.0;
    double _newValue = 0.0;

    _animationController = AnimationController(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800), vsync: this);
    _anim = Tween<double>(begin: _originalValue, end: _newValue)
        .animate(_animationController)..addListener(() {
          setState(() {
          });
    });

    _localPoints = 0;
    _valueCompleted = 0;
    super.initState();

  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    _originalValue = _newValue;

    if (Provider.of<AnswerManager>(context).pageTilesCompleted &&
        _valueCompleted != 0) {
      _localPoints++;
    } else {
      _localPoints = Provider.of<AnswerManager>(context).points;

    }
    _valueCompleted =
        _localPoints / Provider.of<AnswerManager>(context).totalTilesPerPage;
    
    _newValue = _valueCompleted;
    
    _animationController.forward();
    
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('original value $_originalValue and new value $_newValue');
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _animationController,
      builder: (context, i) => LinearProgressIndicator(
        value: _anim.value,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to update `_anim` each time `_newValue` changes its value, BTW you don need to call `addListener` on it

Comment: but actually, instead of those `Tween`s, `AnimatedController`s, `didChangeDependencies()` etc you should use a custom `ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget` - the docs say: *"An abstract class for building widgets that animate changes to their properties. Widgets of this type will not animate when they are first added to the widget tree. Rather, when they are rebuilt with different values, they will respond to those changes by animating the changes over a specified duration."*

Answer (score 0):

Use set state
This will change the state as user will answer